# cube root of unity problem

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Suppose $x$ is a cube root of unity with $x \neq 0$.  Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are the points on the complex plane defined by $x$ and $x^2$. If $O$ is the origin, then what is the angle between $OP$ and $OQ$?

Comment: Do you mean `x does not =1`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a homework problem (and seems mistyped).  The asker should show that he has tried to solve it.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Indeed

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Simply cube root of unity divides the circle of radius one centered at origin into 3 equal parts (in argard plane). What does it tell you about the angles?